# Get a Json format for a Seq of a generic type

Tags: json, scala, generics, play-json

I have an abstract class with a generic type which gets a Json format for that generic type from its subclass. But the abstract class also needs a Json format of a sequence of that type. Is there any way in Scala to get a Json format of a sequence of things based only on the format of those things?

I'm using the Play Json framework.

Here's an example that doesn't follow my case exactly but provides a good indication of what I want to achieve:

```
  package scalatest

  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import scala.concurrent.Await
  import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
  import java.util.UUID
  import scala.util.control.NonFatal
  import play.api.libs.json.Format
  import play.api.libs.json.Json

  object Banana {

     def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val f: Format[Seq[Banana]] = getSeqFormat(Json.format[Banana])
     }

     def getSeqFormat[T](format: Format[T]): Format[Seq[T]] = {
        ??? // TODO implement
     }
  }

  case class Banana(color: String)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to serialize bananas into JSON objects then the only thing you need to do is define the `Banana` **implicit** json format, the others (like Seq format for example) are built-in within play:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Banana(color: String)
object Banana {
  implicit val jsonFormat = Json.writes[Banana]
}

object PlayJsonTest extends App {
  val bananas = Seq(Banana("yellow"), Banana("green"))
  println(Json.toJson(bananas)) // [{"color":"yellow"},{"color":"green"}]
}
```

This also works for other types because the `Json#toJson` method is defined as follows:

```scala
// Give me an implicit `Writes[T]` and I know how to serialize it
def toJson[T](o: T)(implicit tjs: Writes[T]): JsValue = tjs.writes(o)
```

The defaults are implicitly used and those include a format for most of the collections. You can find them [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/DefaultWrites.html).

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it does not work for my question. If you have a format for Bananas, Play implicitly gives you a format for a Seq of Bananas. However, this does not apply to a format of a generic type.